# Syntax error unexpected token '>'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, safari9

I've been testing my JS code on different browsers but it doesn't seem to work on some of them and on mobile either.

JS

```
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();
```

By reading this question I understood that the problem could be related to '=>' because it is a ES6 element and not all the browsers support it. But as you can see here it seems to be the way to get those json data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Is there a way to avoid using '=>' in this function to make it work on all the browsers?

Here the error that I get on Safari 9 for example:

[image]

I tried some solutions but now I get this error:

[image]

posts are not printed yet, any idea?

Comment: Yes, use normal `function` syntax. That is, if there are any browsers that support `fetch()` but not ES6 arrow functions. IDK

Comment: You cannot use "lambda" without transpilers yet. Use Babel for example

Comment: How come the error actually states it's from an anonymous function,  if it doesn't support arrow functions? Are you sure the error is related to that?

Comment: Safari 9 doesn’t support Fetch API either so fixing the arrow functions is just a start. On the other hand Safari 9 is three years old and has 0.03% market share so personally I wouldn’t really worry about it.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: I'm testing in on different browsers but the error(screenshot) comes from Safari9. The real problem is that it is not even working on IOS (all safari versions)

Comment: you need fetch Pollyfill. and for now avoid using arrow function (=>). if you want better  browser support.

Comment: It never works on IOS, I just tried with iphone7 and Safari10 but I still get blank space and Safari10 is quite recent

Comment: check my answer on Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use fetch polyfill and old function syntax not the new arrow function syntax of es6.

```js
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.4/fetch.js"></script>
<div id="newsTitle"></div>
<div id="newsContent"> </div>
```

**Browser Support For Fetch API polyfill**

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari 6.1+
- Internet Explorer 10+

Answer (score 2):

Just use normal function syntax instead of ES6 arrow-syntax:

```
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();
```

Most browsers that don't support ES6 arrow-syntax are unlikely to support the Fetch API. For those I would suggest using another form of HTTP request, or using a Polyfill, like [GitHub's](https://github.github.io/fetch/)

Comment: Any idea why posts are not printed yet and I get this error now: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fetch. I'm editing my question with the screenshot

Comment: As I wrote in my comment,  not all browsers support the fetch API. In that case you need to use some other form of HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal function instead of a lambda:

```
"use strict";

function req1() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json){
        var title = json.title;
        var body = json.body;
        document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
        document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();
```

---

Just write

```
.then(function(json){
```

Instead of

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

---

Also, if you're not sure about the ES6 Syntax in your script, you can use something like [babel](http://babeljs.io):

https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines

`then(response => response.json())`

To

`.then(function(response){ response.json() })`

And

`.then(json => {`

To

`.then(function (json) {`

**Full Code:**

```
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
   .then(function(response){ response.json()})
   .then(function (json){
     var title = json.title;
     var body = json.body; 
     document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
     document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
     document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
   });
}
req1();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use a simple request

```
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
 var json = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
 alert(json.title);
```